# Cannot read property 'classList' of null and overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, overlay

kind of stuck here..

So I have these button accordions which I'm going to fill with content but this will do for now. The panels will be filled with content when I get the functions up and working. All the panels display when the button is being pressed **EXCEPT** for the first accordion. I checked the console and came up with this error:*"Cannot read property 'classList' of null"*. Any ideas on what to do? Tried to change the script somehow, but didn't seem to work.

Another thing that I can't seem to get working are my panel overlays. I want my panel overlays to cover up the rest of the content on the page, whenever a button is being pressed. The button should be active so it can go back to its original theme. I tried to fix it with some "z-index" but didn't seem to quite respond. I also have a script where I tried to make the buttons in my container active but didn't worked out.

Any suggestions?

Here's my code so far:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {

    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

head {
  text-align: left;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

button h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 700px;
}

.container div.active {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    margin: 2%;
  }
  button.accordion.active,
  button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 1</h3></div></button>

  <div class="panel">

    <h1> hej </h1>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 2</h3></div></button>

  <div class="panel">

    <h1> hej </h1>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 3</h3></div></button>

  <div class="panel">

    <h1> hej </h1>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 4</h3></div></button>

  <div class="panel">

    <h1> hej </h1>

  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 5</h3></div></button>

  <div class="panel">

    <h1> hej </h1>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is totally messed up. You can not just open and close tags depending on the birds flying outside the window. To be more specific this does not work `<button class="accordion"><h3>Random 5</h3></div></button>` never! Then why use `nextElementSibling` ?

Comment: Validate your HTML
`Error: Element h3 not allowed as child of element button in this context.`  https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery? btw, for accordion like this, normally for each accordion you should wrap it on a parent element.

Comment: @caramba  It worked, thanks for helping out. Any ideas on how to make my panel cover up the rest of the content when a button is being pressed?

Comment: @chiquyet I'll try it out, thanks.

Comment: @epascarello Fixed it, thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

works fine on my side, you just need to correct your mark up on the button declaration. there are excess closing divs `</div>`.

```
<div class="container">

  <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 1</h3>     </button>

   <div class="panel">

     <h1> hej </h1>

   </div>

   <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 2</h3>  </button>

   <div class="panel">

   <h1> hej </h1>

   </div>

   <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 3</h3>  </button>

   <div class="panel">

   <h1> hej </h1>

   </div>

   <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 4</h3>  </button>

   <div class="panel">

   <h1> hej </h1>

   </div>

   <button class="accordion"><h3>Random 5</h3>  </button>

   <div class="panel">

   <h1> hej </h1>

   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Worked out, thanks.. can't believe i missed the divs.. Thanks.